# How to add complex conditional code in visualforce - Multi-Currency

Tags: visualforce-component, multi-currency, outputtext

I have the following code in visualforce:

```
<apex:variable value="{!Opportunity.Amount-Opportunity.Descuento_Autorizado__c}" var="descontado"/>
   {!IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode=="USD",
   <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,##0.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!descontado}"/>
        </apex:outputText>,
        <apex:outputText value="Q{0, number, ###,##0.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!descontado}"/>
        </apex:outputText>)}
```

I'm 99% sure this isn't even the correct way to do it but just so you have the idea of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to show a different currency symbols using  depending on the value of the currency on the opportunity. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.
For complex logic, you can use an `apex:outputPanel` to determine whether something is rendered.

e.g.

```
<apex:variable value="{!Opportunity.Amount-Opportunity.Descuento_Autorizado__c}" var="descontado"/>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD'}" layout="none">
    <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,##0.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!descontado}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'}" layout="none">
    <apex:outputText value="Q{0, number, ###,##0.00}">
        <apex:param value="{!descontado}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

By adding `layout="none"` to the `apex:outputPanel`, you ensure no wrapping div/span is added to the page.

Or, even simpler you can add the condition to the `apex:outputText` element:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD', '$', 'Q')}{0, number, ###,##0.00}">
    <apex:param value="{!descontado}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need separate rendering for currency. Following format automatically displays currency symbol.

```
 <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}">
```

Code:

```
<apex:variable value="{!Opportunity.Amount-Opportunity.Descuento_Autorizado__c}" var="descontado"/>

<apex:outputPanel layout="none">
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}">
        <apex:param value="{!descontado}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

> Sample output:
>
> $345,670.00

Comment: Both answers are great! The only issue is that in some cases I'm using numbers and showing them as currency so the format won't work. Still great thanks!